# How to stop the backspace to move the cursor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have the following html.

```
<p contenteditable="true">
  <span class="myclass"><img src="image_source"></span>
  A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  <span class="myclass"><img src="image_source"></span>
  A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</p>
```

As you see this p tag and all the spans inside this p tag are editable.
Now my question is: if the cursor is just after the closing span tag i.e `</span>`, then backspace key should not work.I mean if we put some text or even an img tag in this span,the backspace key should not move the cursor back to this span.

Can anybody tell me how it can be done in javascript ?

Thanks to all.

Comment: So this HTML is on the screen? In a textarea? in an editor? in the source only?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, this html will be in tinymce editor.Actually in tinymce editor,everything lies in a p tag.

Comment: @user2826169 You should add that information (about tinymce) to your question.  Some people will not read the comments to look for additional information.

Comment: I can get the editor id by



$("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("p");

Comment: If you explain in case of a textarea, that will also solve my problem.